# Random failure with "click" on casperjs and phantomjs

Tags: random, casperjs

I don't understand, once on ten when i execute this code:

```
casper.then(function() {
        this.waitUntilVisible('#selector');
});
casper.then(function() {
       this.evaluate(function() {
           $('#selector').click();
       });
});
```

click function doest not work, but the selector is present, i see that on my screenshot (I have automatic capture when something fail in my tests).

I also try the casper.click() function but I have the same random result.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to replace then by a wait function.

For example replace in your code :

```
casper.then(function() {
```

by

```
casper.waitForSelector('#selector', function() {
```

You will find more information about waitForSelector in the documentation : http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforselector

Comment: Thank you very much, I try this and I will tell you if it's better.

Comment: Another question: Do you implement the "Page Object Pattern" with casperjs ? I would like to do something as beautiful as site-prism with capybara but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I reexecute my test many times to see if the random result appear for now it's ok but I prefer to execute this test 10 times. Other question, if I dont use casper.then, all the instruction are executed at the same time, did u know that ?